# Set global environment variables from a custom file

Tags: environment-variables, .profile

I am trying to execute a file containing environment variables so that whenever I log in, those variables are immediately accessible.

The `$PATH` variable is defined in `/etc/environment` so underneath that I put:

`. /path/to/variables`

I didn't think variables needed to be `chmod 755` because it works if I run the above manually. But I tried `chmod 755` on it and it still isn't loading on session start.

Inside `/path/to/variables` I have several variables set. They all work fine, but only when I manually run `. /path/to/variables` on each new session.

I have also tried placing `. /path/to/variables` inside my `~/.profile` and restarting the session. Still doesn't work.

Yes, I *could* place my variable declarations inside `/etc/environment` itself, but I want to keep them stored in my own file for organization purposes.

Am I missing something obvious or going about this entirely wrong?

Comment: Can you paste one of the definitions in `/path/to/variables` to see how you are doing it?

Comment: `export app='/var/html/path/to/my/app'` for instance. That's one of several like it. They work when I load the file manually, just not on session start.

Comment: I'm not sourcing a shell script. I just have a file with a list of exports that I am trying to load for the root user on session start.

Comment: Sorry, the above comment was in response to a now deleted comment by another user.

Comment: `/etc/environment` is not a shell script (see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94551/285436)).

Comment: I didn't think it was.

Comment: ... but `.` is a POSIX shell command (called "dot", but often referred to as "source" because some modern shells have an alias named like that). If you want it to be loaded for the root user only, you'll have to place it in root's home folder which is `/root` in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> /etc/environment
>
> This file is specifically meant for system-wide environment variable
>   settings. It is not a script file, but rather consists of assignment
>   expressions, one per line.

That means that you cannnot include something like you meant to.

This information comes from [Environment Variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables). You will find there alternatives for what you were trying to do.

The right way to modify `/etc/profile` is by adding a script to `/etc/profile.d` with the a name in the form *my_script.sh* and a content like this:

```
export MYVAR="my value"
```

As this is now an actual shell script, you can also add something like:

```
. /path/to/variables
```

Comment: Yes but I am also trying it in `~/.profile` , as I stated, and that very thing is already being done in that file with .bashrc

Comment: I updated my answer. Remove the variable from `.bash.rc` and export your variable from a script in `/etc/profile.d`. Logout, login and you will see the value with `echo $MYVAR` (you can also do Ctrl-Alt-F1 and login there and check it. Does it work?

Comment: Yes but is it possible to do this with an include or not? I understand that I can add a file to `profile.d`, or modify `profile`, or modify `environment`, but what I would like to do is to keep all my customizations in my own folder. So is that possible or no?

Comment: Thank you. That last edit was what I was looking for.

Comment: Yes. As stated, the files in /etc/profile.d **are** shell scripts. So yes, you can do what you would do in any shell script, including sourcing an external file. I added to the answer.

Comment: If it works, please consider marking the answer as accepted.

Comment: Actually, that didn't work. It's not accessible to root, but is to ubuntu.

Comment: I just gave up and pasted them all into `/etc/environment`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106496/discussion-between-eduardo-trapani-and-works-for-a-living).